# Excluding path from springboot securization

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak, openapi

I have developed a REST API with secured endpoints using an authentication token from Keycloak.
So far, it had worked like a charm, but when I implemented openApi on it, the endpoint in charge of returning the JSON with the API definition (http://localhost:8080/v3/api-docs), also needs to add a token to work, which is a non-desired behaviour.
How may I exclude such path from the securization?

My current securityConfiguration file is:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.oidc.StandardClaimNames;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.Jwt;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.JwtDecoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.NimbusJwtDecoder;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.authentication.JwtAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.web.SecurityFilterChain;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;



@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableMethodSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Value("${the_value}")
    private String the_jwkSetUri;
    
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http, KeycloakAuthenticationConverter authenticationConverter) throws Exception {
        http.authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize.anyRequest().authenticated())
            .csrf((csrf) -> csrf.disable())
            .oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2ResourceServer) -> oauth2ResourceServer.jwt((jwt) -> jwt.decoder(jwtDecoder())))
            .oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2) -> oauth2.jwt((jwt) -> jwt.jwtAuthenticationConverter(authenticationConverter)));
        return http.build();
    }


    @Bean
    public JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        //CODE OMITTED FOR SIMPLICITY
    } 

    @Component
    static class KeycloakAuthoritiesConverter implements Converter<Jwt, List<SimpleGrantedAuthority>> {
        //CODE OMITTED FOR SIMPLICITY
    }
    
    @Component
    static class KeycloakAuthenticationConverter implements Converter<Jwt, JwtAuthenticationToken> {
        //CODE OMITTED FOR SIMPLICITY
    }    

}
```

My guess is that the resulting chain should be similar to:

```
authorizeHttpRequests((authz) -> authz.requestMatchers("/v3/**").permitAll()).anonymous()
```

but to be honest, I don't know how to implement such chain...

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally, after several tries, I have found the correct syntax:

```
http.authorizeHttpRequests((authorize) -> authorize.requestMatchers("/v3/**").permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated())
            .csrf((csrf) -> csrf.disable())
            .oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2ResourceServer) -> oauth2ResourceServer.jwt((jwt) -> jwt.decoder(jwtDecoder())))
            .oauth2ResourceServer((oauth2) -> oauth2.jwt((jwt) -> jwt.jwtAuthenticationConverter(authenticationConverter)));
```

The above code securizes all endpoints except the one especified in "requestmatchers".